# Slightly different child classes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I genuinely didn't know how to even search for a solution for this problem because it seems so abstract so here I am.

If I have one base class `public abstract class BuildingBaseObject` for example and then 2 child classes,  one containing a RuleTile variable and the other a GameObject variable is there some way to access one of these two variables from a single function (in another class)? I don't want to use the object keyword as it will destroy type permanence and simply doesn't work with my code.

**Repreducable Code**

```
public abstract class BuildingBaseObject {
    //Irrelevant Stuff
}

public class BuildingTile : BuildingBaseObject
{
    public RuleTile ruleTile;
}

public class BuildingObject : BuildingBaseObject
{
    public GameObject objectTile;
}

public class UIShipItem : MonoBehaviour {

    Object buildingObject;
    public object BuildingObject
    {
        get
        {
            if (buildingObject is BuildingObject) return buildingObject as BuildingObject;
            else if (buildingObject is BuildingTile) return buildingObject as BuildingTile;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value is BuildingObject) buildingObject = value as BuildingObject;
            if(value is BuildingTile) buildingObject = value as BuildingTile;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = (buildingObject as BuildingBaseObject).sprite;
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a way to do this nicely or should I just create a base class the UIShipItem and different child classses for each child class of BuildingBaseObject?

Comment: There is no need to do `if (buildingObject is BuildingObject) return buildingObject as BuildingObject; else if (buildingObject is BuildingTile) return buildingObject as BuildingTile;` - just write it as `return buildingObject;`.

Comment: You literally did not answer my question at all. I even specified I **don't** want to use the object keyboard.

Comment: You can do that, *if you really want to*. If it were me. I'd have shadow properties at the subclass level that (at least for the getter) work in a type-safe manner. You should look into *pattern matching* `if` and `switch` statements: `if (buildingObject is BuildingTile tile) return tile;`

Comment: You're going to need to clarify your question and your code. For example *"different child classses for each child class of BuildingBaseObject"*. When I read your question, I assumed that the `buildingObject` field and associated property were typed `BuildingBaseObject`. Why did you type them as `object`

Comment: @LiamBoreback - Sorry, are you saying I didn't answer your question? I wasn't intending to. I was just letting you know that you could shorten the code that you wrote.

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry my mistake I assumed that your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Unity coder, but this works as far as C# is concerned:

```
public class UIShipItem<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : BuildingBaseObject
{
    T buildingObject;
    public T BuildingObject
    {
        get
        {
            return buildingObject;
        }
        set
        {
            buildingObject = value;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = buildingObject.sprite;
        }
    }
}
```

---

You would use this like so:

```
var x = new UIShipItem<BuildingTile>();
```

Comment: I think this will solve my problem. What is this technique called? I would like to read more about it.

Comment: @LiamBoreback - It's called generics. I've added an example of how you would use it.

Comment: @LiamBoreback this would have been the link to it ;) [c# generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) It is btw also how `GetComponent<T>` is implemented ;)